# Orcad DRC Error

Tags: schematics, orcad, drc

I am new to Orcad Cadence 16.5 Schematics. i drawn a schematics and while running DRC, the following error repeatedly occurs for all Components. Please help me to eradicate the below errors:

```
ERROR(ORCAP-1598): More than 8 user properties exist on this part instance J5 
ERROR(ORCAP-1601): Package has same name but different source library. C159 
ERROR(ORCAP-1630): The comment graphic is not a single dashed line I23293272 
ERROR(ORCAP-1607): User properties exist on an object that is not a part instance M_I2C1_SDA
```

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Kasi

Answer (score 1):

-For the error 1630, try this -> http://community.cadence.com/cadence_technology_forums/f/27/t/12775

-1601 error is most likely due to duplicate of that part in another library with the same name. Press P, select all libraries and search for that part. If you can find the second one, delete it, or give another name.